# How to upload local file from Mac via Choose File

Tags: robotframework

I'd like to upload local file from my Mac.
 Here's the partial code from Robot Framework:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Collections
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${file_path}    ${CURDIR}/file/IMG_0738.jpg  

*** Test Cases ***
Case
    Run Keywords    PreconditionLogin
    ...    AND    MyKeyword

*** Keywords ***
PreconditionLogin
    ${chrome_options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-extensions
    #Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --headless
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-gpu
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --no-sandbox
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome_options}
    Set Window Size    1024    768
    Go To    10.11.14.7
    Input Text    //*[@id='UserID']    aaa
    Input Text    //*[@id='Password']    123
    Press Key    //*[@id='Password']    \\13
MyKeyword
    Wait Until Element Is Visible   //*[@class='UploadInput-btn btn'][contains(text(),'UploadFile')]  1s
    Choose File  //*[@class='UploadInput-btn btn'][contains(text(),'UploadFile')]    ${file_path}
```

After RF executed, the error log shows:

> ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

I tried to

```
click element    //*[@class='UploadInput-btn btn'][contains(text(),'UploadFile')]
```

it's working and prompts the file chooser window.

Please refer the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE9tm.png) for the page.

Comment: Please define by which protocol you are uploading. So [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56107077/edit) your question to improve it. If it is [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), tell which request you want to do, then consider using some HTTP client command such as [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/). Also provide some [MCVE] in your question

Comment: If no network communication is involved, then you should not use the "[upload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upload)" word. That word applies to *remote* systems on [computer networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_network). On a local [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system), you simply move or copy [file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file)s, but you don't "upload" them

Comment: Thank you @BasileStarynkevitch.
However it's just a sample from my code, and the original keyword is not 'upload'. ")

Comment: To move or copy files locally, you don't need any `robotframework`s. The core Python interpreter has [file and directory primitives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filesys.html). Just use them!

Comment: The key thing is your probable misunderstanding of what "upload" means. Or you are using the wrong word in your question, and you mean something else. **Please provide some [MCVE] in your -still very unclear- question.** If English is (like for me) not your native language, check your terminology in some dictionnary

Comment: But your question still lacks a necessary [MCVE], and that is required on StackOverflow questions

Comment: Update the content of question, and hope someone would give me hint about this. :)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: the OP is clearly wanting to upload files, not copy files locally. I think your comments are only adding confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locator you give to `Choose file` must point to an input element, not a button. You should not click the button since it will open a dialog which your test can't interact with.

Comment: OMG..it works!!! It's not mentioned in [Selenium2Library](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Choose%20File)
Thank you so much, Mr Oakley.

Comment: @AllenHe: the documentation for the current version of the library says _"Inputs the file_path into file **input field** locator."_

Comment: Yes..I misunderstood what it means.
I consider that input field is something like text field, what a fool I am!!